# Group By & Where MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, where-clause

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the query below to correctly retrieve Google marker data from a MySQL database.

```
SELECT l.locationid, f.locationid, l.locationname, l.osgb36lat, l.osgb36lon, count(f.locationid) as totalfinds 
  FROM detectinglocations as l 
  LEFT JOIN finds AS f ON l.locationid=f.locationid 
  GROUP BY l.locationid
```

I'm now trying to add to this by adding a `where` clause, to be more specific `where userid='$userid'`.

I've tried adding this extra clause in various positions within the query, and I'm sure that this is perhaps just a beginners mistake, but I just can't get the query to work.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps look at this and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the where clause right before GROUP BY.

Comment: Hi @dcp, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post and agreeing to help. I've tried your suggestion, and it works brilliantly. When the time delayed has past, I'll show this as my accepted answer. Once again many thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

In joins, `WHERE` condition comes after `ON` statement

If `userid` is there in table `detectinglocations` then use

```
SELECT l.locationid, f.locationid, l.locationname, l.osgb36lat, l.osgb36lon, count(f.locationid) as totalfinds 
FROM detectinglocations as l 
LEFT JOIN finds AS f ON l.locationid=f.locationid 
WHERE l.userid='$userid'
GROUP BY l.locationid
```

If `userid` is there in table `finds` then use

```
SELECT l.locationid, f.locationid, l.locationname, l.osgb36lat, l.osgb36lon, count(f.locationid) as totalfinds 
FROM detectinglocations as l 
LEFT JOIN finds AS f ON l.locationid=f.locationid 
WHERE f.userid='$userid'
GROUP BY l.locationid
```

Comment: Hi @Fahim Parkar, thank you for taking the time to help me with this. You're suggestion virtually mirrored another answer I received and it works great. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT l.locationid, f.locationid, l.locationname, l.osgb36lat, l.osgb36lon, count(f.locationid) as totalfinds 
          FROM detectinglocations as l 
          LEFT JOIN finds as f on l.locationid=f.locationid 
          WHERE userid=".(int)$userid." 
          GROUP BY l.locationid";
```

I also have added (int) to your variable to "sanitize" an unknow (for me) var

Comment: Hi @Luis Siqot, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post and helping. I tried you suggested code, and unfortunately I was unable to get the query to work. I have however accepted an earlier suggestions as this works absolutely fine. Kind regards

Comment: all of us are here to help, plese notice that my anwser is the same as your accepted anwser, plus the advice to be careful with sql injection.